# is it a must to specify chromedriver in Selenium anymore?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been seeing things like you need to specify the location of your chrome driver in order to run selenium but I have been able to run it without doing that

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("example.com")
```

it still runs but why? also is it possible to specify a specific version of chrome to run?

Answer (score 0):

No, not anymore. With `v4.6.0`(and onwards), selenium has introduced a package known as Selenium Manager. This will handle the setting up of browser drivers.

**Selenium Manager:** It is a new tool that helps to get a working environment to run Selenium out of the box. Beta 1 of Selenium Manager will configure the browser drivers for Chrome, Firefox, and Edge if they are not present on the PATH.

So, regarding your second question: Yes, you can specify a specific version of your choice if you wish to.

References:
https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/webdrivers/4.6.0
https://lakshminarayanan-ganesan.medium.com/whats-new-in-selenium-4-6-0-beta-8c9bb865047d